# How do I resize an Amazon EBS backed volume programmatically in an EC2 running Windows?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud

Looks like the only way to resize an Amazon EBS volume is to [take snapshot, dismount, create a larger volume from the snapshot, mount the latter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550790/growing-amazon-ebs-volume-sizes).

Now my program is running on a Windows EC2 instance and sees that it's out of disk space. How can the program resize the EBS volume the root partition resides on?

Answer (score 0):

Use command "diskpart". For windows have a look here : Use http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415
Following are the steps I followed for a non-root disk (basic not dynamic disk)

Once you have taken a snapshot, dismounted the old EBS volume (say 600GB) and created a larger EBS volume (say 1TB) and mounted this new EBS volume - you would have to let Windows know of the resizing (from 600GB to 1TB) so at command prompt (run as administrator)

> diskpart.exe
>
> select disk=9
>
> select volume=Z
>
> extend

[my disk 9,volume labelled Z, was a volume of size 1TB created from an ec2-snapshot of size 600GB - I wanted to resize 600GB to 1TB and so could follow the above steps to do this.]