# How to increase the Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS)?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, storage, amazon-ebs

Once you run out of space, is there easier way to increase the Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS) storage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550790/growing-amazon-ebs-volume-sizes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean an easier way?

You create a snapshot of your current volume. Then use that snapshot as the basis for a new volume with increased size.

Comment: That's what I do .. usually with some tar magic.

Comment: Don't forget to resize the filesystem to the new volume size.