# Swap disappears when stopping an ebs backed instance.

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, ubuntu-11.10

My instance swap file is disappearing when I start my instance.

I have an Ubuntu ec2 instance, and I follow the "Four-step Process to Add Swap File" instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/512MiB.swap bs=1024 count=524288
sudo chmod 600 /mnt/512MiB.swap
sudo mkswap /mnt/512MiB.swap
sudo swapon /mnt/512MiB.swap
```

I then changed my /etc/fstab to include:

```
/mnt/512MiB.swap  none  swap  sw  0 0
```

Since I am using a much bigger swap, this process takes some time, and I don't want to do it every time I start. I would rather pay for the storage. However, when I start my instance, the swap has disappeared. If I type 'top', the instance does not have a swap file in use.

What should I do?

Comment: There might be a startup/shutdown script that cleans out /mnt of any non mount-point files. Try using /tmp, or preferably some other directory that's not likely to be auto-cleaned.

Comment: There isn't enough space there; I am looking for 200GB swap. I have a very memory intensive task I need to run once or twice a week that runs overnight.

Comment: memory intensive and swap don't get along. swap = disk = many orders of magnitude SLOWER than memory.

Comment: I think this may be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550790/growing-amazon-ebs-volume-sizes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance you are using has [EBS](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) backed [Root Device Storage](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html), all [EC2 instance types](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) still have the [EC2 instance storage](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html) (also known as an *ephemeral store*) available for use as well, and the smaller instance types (e.g. m1.small and c1.medium) have it attached and mounted at `/mnt` by default even (the larger ones not!).

The most important characteristic of this storage type to be aware of is, that the *data on the instance store volumes persists only during the life of the associated Amazon EC2 instance*.

This statement is nowadays a tiny bit misleading, insofar it applies to stopping an EBS backed instance as well (not rebooting though), i.e. the moment you stop that instance, the ephemeral volume mounted at `/mnt` is detached and deleted and all data stored there is lost, including your swap file of course; once you start the instance again, a new ephemeral volume will be attached and mounted at `/mnt`.

### Solution

You can still use the EC2 instance storage (which is plentiful and free of charge) if you exactly know what you are doing (see section *Background* below), e.g. it is a perfect option for **strictly temporary data** or anything that can be recreated easily on demand, like a cache for example.

A swap file is matching this requirements as well of course, so you simply need to create a script with the commands outlined in your question and execute it on instance start to recreate the swap file. You should put a guard in place though, because the instance storage survives reboots, i.e. you neither need nor should recreate the swap file on reboots, just with real stop/start cycles.

---

#### Background

The instance storage used to be the only storage option when Amazon EC2 was first introduced, but the resulting severe limitations for everyday usage have fortunately been remedied with the [Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonEBS.html) you are using as well accordingly. Eric Hammond has recently provided a great summary why [You Should Use EBS Boot Instances on Amazon EC2](http://alestic.com/2012/01/ec2-ebs-boot-recommended), addressing this very topic:

> If you are just getting started with Amazon EC2, then use EBS boot
>   instances and stop reading this article. Forget that you ever heard
>   about instance-store and accept my apology that I just mentioned it.
>   Once you are completely comfortable with using EBS boot instances on
>   EC2, you may (or may not) want to come back here and read why you made
>   a good decision.

Comment: Any chance you have a script that implements swap on create/start but not on reboot?