# AWS EC2 extension adding disk space redhat

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat

I would like to increase the size of EC2 disk space on **AWS**.
I have **Redhat** AMI that is connected to this volume.

What is the best way to increase the space (without losing the data)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Growing Amazon EBS Volume sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550790/growing-amazon-ebs-volume-sizes)

Answer (score 2):

You can attached [EBS](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) to it.

This is a network based disk that you can create and then attach it to the instance. You can later detach it and attach it again to this or other instances. You can also take snapshot of this disk as backup or to create new EBS from it.

Comment: No. Instance stores are defined (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#StorageOnInstanceTypes) and their data is lost on instance stop/terminate