# AWS SDK for PHP 2 - Change root volume size when creating an Instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

It's relatively easy to create a new instance using PHP by using the [`runInstances()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.Ec2.Ec2Client.html#_runInstances) method.

```
$instance = $ec2->runInstances(array(
    'ImageId'        => AMI_ID,      // AMI ID
    'InstanceType'   => AMI_TYPE,    // m1.medium etc.
    'MinCount'       => 1,           // Minimum to create
    'MaxCount'       => 1,           // Maximum to create
    'SecurityGroups' => SEC_NAME,    // Security Group Name
    'KeyName'        => KEY_NAME     // Key Pair to use
))->toArray();                       // Get back our data in an array
```

However, the point of the API is to be able to do everything you can do with the front-end on the amazon website, in a tenth of the time and with your own code.

With that in mind, I need to do the following:

[image: AWS Request Instances Wizard - Root Volume]

On the front-end, I can change the **Volume Size** to, say, 40GB.

**How can I ask for a 40GB Volume Size when creating a new Instance with PHP?** It could even be run *after* the instance is created, as long as it's automatic - I should be able to do this programatically.

How can I achieve what I require using the [AWS SDK for PHP 2](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp2/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track. In the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.Ec2.Ec2Client.html#_runInstances) for `runInstances()`, there is a parameter `BlockDeviceMappings` that contains another parameter `Ebs` that contains the paramenter you're looking for `VolumeSize`. This is untested code.

```
$instance = $ec2->runInstances(array(
'ImageId'                => AMI_ID,      // AMI ID
'InstanceType'           => AMI_TYPE,    // m1.medium etc.
'MinCount'               => 1,           // Minimum to create
'MaxCount'               => 1,           // Maximum to create
'SecurityGroups'         => SEC_NAME,    // Security Group Name
'KeyName'                => KEY_NAME,    // Key Pair to use
'BlockDeviceMappings' => array(          // How block devices are mapped to instance
   array(
     'Ebs' => array(                     // EBS Volume Info
        array(
            'VolumeSize' => 40           // Volume Size
        )
    )
)
)
))->toArray();                           // Get back our data in an array
```

Answer (score 1):

This is no different than how is done using the command line tools. First you need to figure out the snapshot ID of the AMI you will be launching. You do this by querying the properties of the AMI. One of the values returned is the snapshot ID. Then you use that ID to run the instance by specifying the snapshot ID you will use and also the size.

The documentation here : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonEC2/run_instances

explains this needs to be passed with the BlockDeviceMapping array. Then within that array you need to use 'Ebs' and specify the SnapshotId and VolumeSize.

If you pass all those parameters in the runinstance call it will launch with your desired size.

Comment: I'd prefer your answer as it is an optimized way to [set the size](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.Ec2.Ec2Client.html#_runInstances) of EBS by [querying](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonEC2/run_instances) first the VolumeSize of its Snapshot.