# Please help me check the actual size of my volume AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS EC2 instance and recently I tried extending my secondary volume and then connecting it back to my ec2 instance. I scaled it to 200 GB from 8GB. Though I have confirmed from the dashboard that its 200GB but I don't know why `df .` shows that my volume size is only 8GB?

`df .`  shows : [image]

`lsblk` shows [image]

whom should I trust ?

Which one is showing the actual size ?

Comment: ``df`` is showing the correct size

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550790/growing-amazon-ebs-volume-sizes

Answer (score 2):

The volume is 200 GB, but the filesystem is still only 8 GB.

You need to resize the filesystem bigger to occupy the entire volume.

Use the `resizefs` command to extend the filesystem to the full volume size.

Comment: Thanks it worked. The command I used to solve is ```sudo resize2fs /dev/xvdf1``` since my file system was ext4. This command can be used for a Linux ext2, ext3, or ext4 file system.